# Combining multiple timeseries points (or not?)

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, forecasting, dimensionality-reduction

This must be a common idea that many people before me thought of.

I have a timeseries and I want my model to try to predict an output based on not just the data at the current point in time but on the last N points (including now).

For N=1, we take only the current moment $X_t$
For N=2 we can simply to take the delta $X_t$ - $X_{t-1}$.
For N>2 ??

**How do we combine the last N point into one when N>2? Is there a function (like subtraction) that would capture the history?**

---

The other question is whether this is actually a good idea at all. We can just feed the data as it is to the model i.e. take the last N points as our features rather than doing feature reduction.

This question is less important because I can just experiment with both and see which one yields a better score.

---

Note: my data is basically = (last trade price and volume, top bids and asks with volume, timestamp)

Note: Data is **not sampled at a regular interval.**

Comment: Look up exponential smoothing for time series analysis.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [forecasting](/questions/tagged/forecasting). You may want to look at previous questions in that tag.

I like to recommend [*Forecasting: Principles and Practice* by Hyndman and Athanasopoulos](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/), a free online forecasting textbook. The best parts for you would be the chapters on [Exponential Smoothing](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/7) and the one on [ARIMA (autoregressive integrated moving average)](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/8) processes - what you describe is an autoregressive thing.

Classical forecasting algorithms presuppose regularly sampled data, but I'd expect them to work reasonably well in your case, too.